# How to view the thingsboard data present in cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, thingsboard

I have installed thingsboard in ubuntu and also configured it to use the cassandra database, my question is that how can i view the thingsboard device data that is present in the cassandra database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly query the database using CQL (Cassandra Query Language). I suggest using **cqlsh**, this is a quick but complete tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_cqlsh.htm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right and you are looking for some kind of cassandra database GUI, you could try the nosqlmanager:

http://www.nosqlmanager.com/cassandra

Comment: yes nosql manager is an option but then in order to use it for linux we first need to install wine then only we can use nosql manager. But then using terminal only if we fire capture command and specify path to an file, then the result of the queries that we use is stored in that particular file, this is the alternative i came across.